# Não executar evento em apenas uma pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código em todas as páginas

```js
$( ":submit" ).click(function() {
    $("#escondido").css("display","block");
  });
```

Este código esta em um arquivo blabla.js, e é incluido com php no topo de todas as páginas do site, mais em apenas uma página eu não quero que esse evento ocorra, há a possibilidade de desativar ela apenas nesta página sem ter que retirar o blabla.js

Comment: adicione a tag php, até porque é mais fácil fazer por ele

Answer (score 1):

Na pagina ao qual não quero que mostre a div.. coloquei em um evento

```js
$("#escondido").css("visibility","hidden");
```

Assim ele "Executa" mais não é visível.

Comment: fica melhor se ele der um `("display", "none")`, assim o tamanho do elemento não será contabilizado

Comment: Tentei utilizar o display none, mais não funcionou.. ai resolvi colocar o visibility mesmo..

Comment: Se o tamanho estiver atrapalhando, você pode usar `$("#escondido").remove();` que o elemento vai ser completamente removido.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função hide() da JQuery:

```js
$( ":submit" ).click(function() { 
    $("#escondido").hide();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='escondido'>Escondido</div>

<input type='submit' value="Submit"/>
```